# Redirect in function of the referer

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this index.php to redirect the users to another pages in function of the referrer that he comes. If the user comes from a referrer that are not listed he should go to specific url.

All goes fine except when the user comes from any referer that not are listed. In this case, the site not make anything (in blank in the same domain). I not see where are the error.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["redirect"])) {
  $hash = $_POST["redirect"];

  if ($hash !== "") {
    $origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";
    $destination = "";

    if($origin == 'http://www.ads1.net/click/cc1/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example1.com';
    } else if($origin == 'http://www.ads2.net/click/cc2/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example2.com';
    } else if($origin == 'http://www.ads3.net/click/cc3/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example3.com';
    } else if($origin == 'http://www.ads4.net/click/cc4/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example4.com';
    } else if($origin == 'http://www.ads5.net/click/cc5/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example5.com';
    } else {
      $destination = 'http://www.anothersite.com';
    }

    if($destination != "") {
      echo "<script>window.location.href = '".$destination."';</script>";
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: did you tried to use `switch`

Comment: It's probably because `$_POST["redirect"]` is not set or empty when the users comes from a referrer that isn't listed.

Comment: try logging out stuff at breakpoints... I don't know what you're trying to do exactly, but I've traced your code and it looks like it's doing what you're saying you want it to do

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Can you give me an example of how the code would look with my example? Excuse me but my technical knowledge is very basic.

Comment: First we need to understand what specifically you're trying to do... I'm a bit confused

Comment: just redirect the user to a different URL for each specified source, and if the source is any other take it to another URL (in the example I have set, it would redirect to anothersite.com)

Comment: @dGRAMOP can you help me with this please? many thanks

Comment: @Nick and how I can solve this? Could you tell me how the final code would look with my example in mind? Many thanks

Comment: I've posted an answer with some sample code. See how that works for you and comment on it if there are any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this. If `$_POST['redirect']` is not set, it will redirect to `http://www.anothersite.com`. Otherwise if `$_POST['redirect']` is not empty, it will redirect according to `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. The only case in which the user will not be redirected is if `$_POST['redirect']` is set but empty (i.e. `$_POST['redirect'] === ''`); I have left a comment in an else block there, you may decide to redirect from there as well?

```
$destination = "";
if (isset($_POST["redirect"])) {
  $hash = $_POST["redirect"];

  if ($hash !== "") {
    $origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : "";

    if($origin == 'http://www.ads1.net/click/cc1/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example1.com';
    } else if($origin == 'http://www.ads2.net/click/cc2/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example2.com';
    } else if($origin == 'http://www.ads3.net/click/cc3/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example3.com';
    } else if($origin == 'http://www.ads4.net/click/cc4/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example4.com';
    } else if($origin == 'http://www.ads5.net/click/cc5/') {
      $destination = 'http://www.example5.com';
    } else {
      $destination = 'http://www.anothersite.com';
    }
  }
  else {
    // $_POST['redirect'] is set but empty (=== '')
    // if you want to redirect for this case, add a URL here as well e.g.
    // $destination = 'http://www.anothersite.com'
   }
}
else {
  $destination = 'http://www.anothersite.com';
}
if($destination != "") {
  echo "<script>window.location.href = '".$destination."';</script>";
}
```